# Force redirect from HTTPS to HTTP in Drupal 7 Multitsite?

Tags: users, multi-sites, uri

I'm trying to serve a Kaltura video running on CentOS 6+ on one server, by plugging the Object code for embedded video inside a node body (or even using the Kaltura Drupal module), running on a Drupal 7 multisite on Ubuntu 10.04LTS.

Most browsers accept it but Chrome, which denies the request as being insecure content. We serve all our D7 sites on HTTPS, forced redirect. But now I want to only serve ONE of the multisite as HTTP so that it could show this Kaltura video, and not have Chrome hiccup.

Here's what I have in the .htaccess file of the D7 parent directory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} !^(/mysite/user)
RewriteRule ^(/.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301]
```

I've tried the Secure Login module, as well as the very close suggestions here - [Redirect /user/login to HTTPS, all other requests to HTTP](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/redirect-user-login-to-https-all-other-requests-to-http), to straight mode rewrite on apache - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816119/using-mod-rewrite-how-do-i-force-https-for-certain-paths-and-http-for-all-othe - and nothing makes sense.

Note: Not a mod-rewrite expert, but I now feel this is somehow attributed to not doing something correctly with Drupal. Currently, when you visit http://mydomain.com/mysite/user - I get this message:

```
You are accessing <mysite> using an unencrypted connection. For your
security, <mysite> only supports account logins using
a secure protocol such as HTTPS.
```

I believe this is a very popular question, but didn't really see anyone else trying to go from secure to insecure on multisite. Please advise. Thanks,!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try and and change the object embed code code to use a protocal-relative URL such as `//YOURSITENAME.COM/some/path/to/video/file.mp4` you can do this easily with a WYSIWYG editor or like `hook_node_view` and regexing for your domain url and an object tag and removing the `http://` or `https://` as needed ...

Simply google for protocol-relative url and you'll find a bunch of information.

Comment: I'll go ahead and try this today, but do I rely on the protocol-relative url WITH the rewrite rules? (I suppose there's one way to find out..)

Comment: You only get a warning from Chrome if your page is HTTPS and some piece of embedded content or iframe is non-HTTPS. The protocol-relative url will keep your embedded content url in _sync_ with however the page was fetched.

Whether or not you want the page itself HTTPS or not is your own business logic.